# Securely transmitting password over TCP Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, security, tcp

I want to write a secure method of authentication over TCP sockets in Java. I've read reasonably extensively on the subject, but I am by no means an expert. There seems to be a bit of variance in opinion on how this is best done.

I know pretty well had to generate my password hashes, but that doesn't do me a whole lot of good if an attacker can simply glean the passwords/password hashes while in transit. So I want to create a reasonably secure method of sending this data across.

The most popular method seems to be using SSL sockets. However, my code will not be used as a single server (as an online game might be) but instead will have many instances run by various consumers. I personally don't have a means to purchase an SSL certificate, and I can't really ask my consumers to do that either. Creating self-signed certificates and then installing them in a keystore for each client seems both difficult and a little insecure. If I were handling all server instances, this would be a much more viable option, since I would only need one certificate, but as it stands now

So I worked on simply securing the TCP socket while performing log ins. I can do this pretty well using a Diffie-Hellman algorithm. However, as I research this, people kept saying to use SSL instead.

How can I securely transmit passwords over Java TCP sockets in an efficient but portable manner?

Comment: 'The means to purchase an SSL certificate' are trivial compared to the costs you are already incurring by asking the question, let alone implementing the answer, assuming you even get one that is both feasible and secure, which is by no means certain.

Comment: Have you considered implementing RSA encryption yourself?

Comment: @EJP Not really sure what you mean by that. I'm currently a one-man company. I'm not rich, I'm  not making any money. Besides, purchasing an SSL certificate isn't really the issue, it's that every client would also have to purchase one, and I'm not sure I want to make that a requirement for using my software.

Comment: @Someone I had looked into that some, but for some reason I thought it wasn't suitable I can't recall why now. That looks like it would work great! Consider adding it as an answer, and as long as I actually did just blow RSA off for no reason, I'll accept it (I'm going to do a little more research first).

Comment: I expressed myself clearly. You can get an SSL certificate for peanuts. Every client would *not* have to purchase one, unless you're doing two-way SSL authentication, which isn't mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered RSA encryption? RSA encryption is the same encryption that SSL uses:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: You may want to include a little more information about what RSA is about. It's a good suggestion, but it doesn't really answer the question. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: Insecure without authentication of at least one of the peers.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). This is exactly for your use case, to exchange keys over a public network. See the [Oracle Diffie-Hellman example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#DH2Ex).

Comment: Insecure without authentication of at least one of the peers.